# Verify signature from dApp on contract

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, keccak, ecdsa

I am creating a signed message using a user address, nonce and number (amount of eth to send) like this:

```
    const ammount = 1;
    const userAddr = await otherAccount.address
    const nonce =  crypto.randomBytes(32)

    const message = ethers.solidityPackedKeccak256(
        ['address', 'bytes32', 'uint256'],
        [userAddr, nonce, ammount]
      );
    
    const signedMessage = await wallet.signMessage(message);
```

i am then sending the signature along with the other params like so:

```
 await contract.call(
            "claimReward",
            [userAddr, nonce, signature, 1], //Arguments
            {}
          );
```

i am then trying to verify the message was signed by the wallet in backend on the contract here:

```
 function claimReward(address user, bytes32 nonce, bytes calldata signature, uint256 amount) public {
    // Perform additional checks if needed

    // Construct message
    bytes32 _message = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(user, nonce, amount));
    bytes32 _messageHash = ECDSA.toEthSignedMessageHash(_message);
    // Verify signature
    require(backendAddress == ECDSA.recover(_messageHash, signature), "Invalid signature.");

    // Check if nonce is valid and hasn't been used before
    require(!usedNonces[nonce], "Nonce already used.");
    usedNonces[nonce] = true;

    // Transfer reward
    payable(user).transfer(amount);

    // Emit event
    emit RewardClaimed(user, amount);
    }
```

I keep getting the invalid signature revert message despite me using the same values on the js and solidity side.  Is there somewhere i am messing up in constructing the signed message on the js side? or is the issue on solidity side? The address recovered on contract side is never the same as the one that signed the message on the app side.  the address recovered changes every time.